# Magento 1.9.1 Not able to edit file in the checkout folder

Tags: magento-1.9

I added some custom fields in the checkout section. But while i try to update the code in the folder

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/onepage.php
```

I couldn't update anything. The code remains the same before showing the last edit date and time as 2014

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to update the **core** files, please **rewrite** it in local then put your changes on it.

I think that these changes will not be taken because maybe this model has been rewritten, look first your local or community code pool.

> Nb: don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: I tried that also